# React TypeError: postCompany is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios, react-hooks

I am making a project in which I have to add a new company in the database. For this I have created an ***export default function component*** named "***CreateCompany***". The entity company has it's own ***GlobalState*** and ***GlobalReducer***. So all the **CRUD** functions for ***Company*** are present in the ***GlobalProvider*** in the ***GlobalState***.

So, I run the application, enter the data in the ***CreateCompany*** component which is a form that takes user input and uses state to store the information in an object and passes that object onto the ***postCompany( )*** in the ***GlobalProvider*** and an error shows up as follows:

```
TypeError: postCompany is not a function

onCompanySubmit
D:/Documents/Code/Al Fayda Al Wataniya/Daybook/server/client/src/components/Company/createCompany.js:24
  21 |            name
  22 |        }
  23 |        // console.log(newCompany)
> 24 |        postCompany(newCompany)
     | ^  25 |    }
  26 | 
  27 |    return (
```

I also have added the functionality to create a new user with the same code, that works but this doesn't.

**CreateCompany Component Code:**

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../../context/Company/CompanyGlobalState'
import '../../App.css'

export default function CreateCompany() {
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
    const [poBox, setPOBox] = useState('')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    const { postCompany } = useContext(GlobalContext)

    const onCompanySubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const newCompany = {
            phone,
            email,
            address,
            poBox,
            name
        }
        // This is the call to the function that will insert new data in the database.
        // The code works till here. The issue lies in the fact that when postCompany() is called,
        // it is not considered a function.
        postCompany(newCompany)
    }
```

**CompanyGlobalState:**

```js
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import CompanyReducer from './CompanyReducer'

// Initial State
const initialState = {
    companies: [],
    error: null,
    loading: true
}

// Create Context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState)

// Provider
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CompanyReducer, initialState)

    // Actions
    // This is where the problem lies, the compiler doesn't even enter the function
    // The error "TypeError: postCompany is not a function" is given
    async function postCompany(company) {
        console.log(company)
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/companies', company, config)
            dispatch({
                type: 'CREATE_COMPANY',
                payload: res.data.data
            })
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: 'COMPANY_ERROR',
                payload: error.response.data.error
            })   
        }
        
    }

    return(<GlobalContext.Provider value={{
        companies: state.companies,
        error: state.error,
        loading: state.loading,
        getCompanies,
        deleteCompany,
        postCompany
    }}>
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>)
}
```

I am using axios for communication between the frontend and backend. I am confused and don't have much experience with React. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Try `const tmp = useContext(GlobalContext);` followed by `console.log(tmp);` what do you see?

Comment: It is what it says it is, `postCompany` is not a function. You probably didn't wrap `CreateCompany` with the `GlobalProvider`. Try to log `const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext); console.log(globalContext);` and see what it yields, it'll probably log `initialSate`.

Comment: @JohnSmith i tried what you said, and you are right, it gives the `initialState`. How do i solve this, can you guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateCompany` needs to have `GlobalProvider` above it.

Somewhere up the tree.

```
<GlobalProvider>
     <CreateCompany/>
</GlobalProvider>
```

It obviously doesn't need to be immediately nested as above, it can be a grand-grand-grand-grand-grandchildren or whatever.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to @JohnSmith. Since i have multiple global states, each for a different entity, i.e., a different global state for `Company`, different for `User`, etc, i had forgotten to include these in the `App.js` file. Thanks again @JohnSmith for helping me figure this out. Now the only question left is how to use multiple global providers in a single `App.js` file. If anyone has ideas on this, please refer them to me.

Comment: The most obvious solution is to have different contexts. `UserContext`, `CompanyContext` and so on. A catch-all "global" context is a bad idea.